# Как добавить два виджета в QStackedWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qstackedwidget, alignment

Допустим, я у меня есть `QLineEdit` и `QLabel`.

Как я могу их запихнуть в `QStackedWidget` оба и выровнять по центру?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        Qwidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.label = QLabel('<h2>Hello World</h2>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.stack = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.stack)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        
        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.stack)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

я видимо плохо прочитал ваш вопрос.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stack1 = QTextEdit('TextEdit')
        self.stack2 = QLabel('<h2>Hello World</h2>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.stack1)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.stack2)

        self.lestWidget = QListWidget()
        self.lestWidget.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.lestWidget.addItems(['TextEdit', 'Label'])
        self.lestWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lestWidget)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)

    def display(self, i):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(i)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Bitchdragon я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Да нет, мне нужно было то, что вы написали в первый раз

Comment: Спасибо за помощь:)